# Does bool variable in kernel need to be synchronized

Tags: cuda

I have a kernel consisting of a for loop that searches through an array for a specific int value. I'm using a grid block of 256 threads to do this. However, when one thread finds the value, I want to let the other threads know to exit. Currently I'm using a boolean flag, but I'm not sure if its working properly. My concern is synchronization.

```
__device__ bool found;

__global__
void search()
{
   for(int i = threadIdx.x; i<1000000; i += stride)
   {
        if(found == true)
        {
            break;
        } 
        else if(arr[i] = x)
        {
             found = true;
             break;
        }
   }
}  

int main()
{
    bool flag = false;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(found, &flag, sizeof(bool), 0,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

Comment: it's very likely that your concerns could be addressed by marking the `bool`  variable as [`volatile`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#volatile-qualifier).  As an extra measure, you could use a [`threadfence()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) call immediately after the only point in your kernel code that writes to that `bool` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, you can probably achieve what you want by declaring the global device flag to be  `volatile`, which will inhibit caching, and by using a memory fence function. There really isn't a global synchronization primitive which would do want you want other than the new grid synchronization mechanism introduced in CUDA 9 and new hardware, but that probably isn't necessary in this case.  Turning your pseudocode into a toy example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

__device__ volatile bool found;
__device__ volatile size_t idx;

template<bool docheck>
__global__
void search(const int* arr, int x, size_t N)
{
   size_t i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
   size_t stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;

   for(; (i<N) && (!found); i += stride)
   {
        if(arr[i] == x)
        {
             if (docheck) found = true;
             idx = i;
             __threadfence();
             break;
        }
   }
}  

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 1 << 24;
    const size_t findidx = 280270;
    const int findval = 0xdeadbeef;

    thrust::device_vector<int> data(N,1);
    data[findidx] = findval;

    bool flag = false;
    size_t zero = 0;


    {
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(found, &flag, sizeof(bool));
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(idx, &zero, sizeof(size_t));
    int blocks, threads;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&blocks, &threads, search<false>);
    search<false><<<blocks, threads>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(data.data()), findval, N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    size_t result = 0;
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&result, idx, sizeof(size_t)); 
    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;
    }

    {
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(found, &flag, sizeof(bool));
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(idx, &zero, sizeof(size_t));
    int blocks, threads;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&blocks, &threads, search<true>);
    search<true><<<blocks, threads>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(data.data()), findval, N);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    size_t result = 0;
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&result, idx, sizeof(size_t)); 
    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and profiling it gives the following:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -o notify notify.cu
$ nvprof ./notify
==3916== NVPROF is profiling process 3916, command: ./notify
result = 280270
result = 280270
==3916== Profiling application: ./notify
==3916== Profiling result:
            Type  Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 GPU activities:   78.00%  1.6773ms         1  1.6773ms  1.6773ms  1.6773ms  void search<bool=0>(int const *, int, unsigned long)
                   19.93%  428.63us         1  428.63us  428.63us  428.63us  void thrust::cuda_cub::core::_kernel_agent<thrust::cuda_cub::__parallel_for::ParallelForAgent<thrust::cuda_cub::__uninitialized_fill::functor<thrust::device_ptr<int>, int>, unsigned long>, thrust::cuda_cub::__uninitialized_fill::functor<thrust::device_ptr<int>, int>, unsigned long>(thrust::device_ptr<int>, int)
                    1.82%  39.199us         1  39.199us  39.199us  39.199us  void search<bool=1>(int const *, int, unsigned long)
```

As you can see, the version which sets the found flag completes the search in 40 microseconds, whereas the version which does not set the flag takes 1.7 milliseconds. Given that the kernel is run with the maximum number of resident blocks in both cases, we can conclude that the early exit mechanism worked correctly and running blocks detected that the required value had been found.

Comment: Really informative answer. How are you getting `nvprof` to display the amount of time it takes for the thread that sets the found flag?

Comment: @Brosef: I'm not. The profiler is measuring the complete  execution time of the kernel.

Comment: Hmm mine is not displaying that. Only shows time for `search(int*, int, int)` and `[CUDA memcpy HtoD]`

Comment: @brosef: Obviously you aren't running my code. Note the code in my answer contains two kernels.

Comment: Awh i see. I havent done much C++ or cuda. What is the `<false>` `<true>` doing when you run the two kernels from `main()`

Comment: Template parameters controlling the kernel kernel behaviour.

Comment: Would it be possible to achieve the same results by moving the `found ` flag variable into `main` and pass it as an argument to the kernel instead?

Comment: Probably, as long as the variable is still declared volatile. Why don'y you try it for yourself?

Comment: Was gonna give it a try. Wasn't sure whether I could tell if its working correctly because of the non-deterministic nature